# React Native: How to decode base64 encoded string?

Tags: utf-8, react-native, base64

I have a string:

`'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`

I can't make any sense of it unless I decode it. However, I've tried installing the `base64` npm package, and the `utf8` package as well but it is complaining that `_utf2.default.decode is not a function. (In \'_utf2.default.decode(bytes)\', \'_utf2.default.decode\' is undefined)`.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js#utf8decodebytestring

```
import base64 from 'base-64';
import utf8 from 'utf8';

  const bytes = base64.decode(validationData);
  const text = utf8.decode(bytes); // <----- fails here
  console.log("base64: ", text);
```

Background: trying to implement in app purchases using this: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils but the `receiptData` is base64 encoded

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to decode it and render it as an image component you can do it like this:

```
const base64 = 'data:image/png;base64, *put your string here*'

<Image source={{uri: base64}} />
```

Comment: unfortunately i'm not using it for images

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

[I found this repository](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode), which appears to be pretty old, but also worked. I don't receive the header (which I didn't need), but I do recieve the payload/data.

I did the following:

```
npm install jwt-decode --save
```

Then, in my app:

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
// Where necessary elsewhere in the code
let decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log('Decoded:',decoded);
```